# docker daemon can't running on ubuntu container

Tags: docker

On my windows 11, I install Docker Desktop and ubuntu image.

On ubuntu container, I want install dapr，but dapr depends on docker

> ## dapr init
>
> ⌛  Making the jump to hyperspace...
> ❌  could not connect to Docker. Docker may not be installed or running

so, then I install docker on ubuntu container, but the docker can't run (I have set export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375).  how to solve this issue?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you install Docker on WSL?

Comment: Without using wsl, install docker on windows11, then install ubuntu container, and then install docker in ubuntu container, the internal docker cann't run